# What is the effect of stopping an AppPool on currently executing requests?

Tags: iis, web-hosting, application-pools, appcmd

It is my understanding that asking an AppPool in IIS to recycle will give *currently active* requests 90 seconds to complete before they are abnormally terminated by the recycle request, while no longer accepting new requests.  What about asking an AppPool to stop?  Does it too have the same spin-down policy?

If it matters, I'm stopping the AppPool via:

```
appcmd.exe stop apppool /apppool.name:"theAppPoolName"
```

- Version: 10.0.14393.0
- Server: Windows Server 2016 / IIS 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, stopping an AppPool (rather than killing its process) does also gracefully shut down the ApplicationPool, giving existing requests time to finish.

So the behavior is the same as for recycling the pool.

Comment: You wouldn't happen you have a reference for this?

Comment: @HiTech - not off top of my head, just many years of experience.